# How can I recreate my colormap made with matplotlib from an adjacency matrix in bokeh

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh, adjacency-matrix, colormap

For a project I have a very large datafile (1000+ people) about how people think about each other. 
It is a square matrix, with all the names of people both on the x and y axis. If you look at the value when it contains the same person on both the x and y axis, the value is 1. For all other people this person will show a value between 0 and 1 or 0.
I already created this in matplotlib, but I am not happy with the result (too small and not interactive) so I try to switch to bokeh. 
However, I'm not familiar enough with bokeh to recreate this on my own.

For the code made for the bokeh extension, I tried to look at the example provided at the gallery of bokeh:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/les_mis.html.

This is how i would like to have it, but I just don't understand it.

So the current code to show the colormap with matplotlib is:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# Read in csv
df = pandas.read_csv('file1.csv', sep=';', index_col=0)

plt.imshow(df.T, aspect='auto', cmap='bwr')

#add the values
for(i, j), value in np.ndenumerate(matrix):
    plt.text(i, j, "%.3f"%value, va='center', ha='center')

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()


print(df)
```

At the moment, this is the result. Apparently I can't show images because this is my first post and I'm brand new here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG1sI.jpg. If this link works, feel free to have a look.

As you can see, it is really small and almost useless. I hope that bokeh with the zoom function can provide a better result.

Comment: You produce a png image of the plot in an inlined fashion in VisualStudio. If you run the code as script via the CLI,  `python myscript.py` you should get the usual interactive matplotlib window automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do *not* want to emulate the link you posted, for the 1000x1000 case. Sending all the coordinates for, and rendering a million individual rects is more than Bokeh or your browser can handle. You would need to [colormap an image](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/image.html), which is much more efficient. But then getting useful axes will take more work. You can use `SingleIntervalTicker` to generate only ticks at specific locations, e.g. if you set the bound of the image to *(-0.5, 999.5)*, then

```
p.yaxis.ticker = SingleIntervalTicker(interval=1, num_minor_ticks=0)
p.yaxis.ticker = SingleIntervalTicker(interval=1, num_minor_ticks=0)
```

will generate a tick at the center of each "cell" of the image. Then to print names instead of numbers you could use tick label overrides:

```
p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {
    0: "some name",
    1: "other name",
    ...
}
```

You would probably want to generate that dict programmatically. But even with all that, I would say this approach has some fundamental issues. If you allow the user to zoom all the way out, the tick labels will collide and overlap one another. You could set `bounds` and `max_interval` on the plot ranges, which might mitigate that.

Overall, I would actually suggest trying to find other visualization approaches altogether, as I do not think this one is very suitable for the 1000x1000 case in any library or tool.

Comment: So would using Holoviews a good solution? Now it is working in matplotlib but we still want to use it on a website. Really thanks for the eleborate answert btw!

Comment: Holoview is not, itself, a plotting library. It can make plots, using matplotlib or Bokeh as a backend. All the same comments above apply if you use Holoviews with the Bokeh backend. The exception to that is you can use Holoview to render the data with Datashader, and then Bokeh plot the resulting *image *which would be perfectly fine for Bokeh. It's the sending and rendering of 1MM individual rectangles that is the problem.